# Regular Expression to find $0.00

Tags: regex, perl

Need to count the number of "$0.00" in a string. I'm using:

```
my $zeroDollarCount = ("\Q$menu\E" =~ tr/\$0\.00//);
```

but it doesn't work. The issue is the `$` sign is throwing the regex off. It works if I just want to count the number of `$`, but fails to find `$0.00`.

How is this a duplicate? Your solution does not address dollar sign which is an issue for me.

Comment: the $ is throwing this off. Your link doesn't address this.

Comment: Actually it does. I still don't think it's a duplicate though. I'm posting an answer explaining what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I can't get it to work, its been 3 days of trying.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the *transliteration operator* [`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html). That doesn't have anything to do with a pattern. You need the *match operator* `m//` instead. And because you want it to find all occurances of the pattern, use the `/g` modifier.

```
my $count = () = $menu =~ m/\$0\.00/g;
```

If we run this program, the output is *2*.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $menu = '$0.00 and $0.00';
my $count = () = $menu =~ m/\$0\.00/g;

print $count;
```

Now lets take a look at what is going on. First, the pattern of the match.

```
/\$0\.00/
```

This is fairly straight-forward. There is a literal `$`, which we need to escape with a backslash `\`. The zero is followed by a literal dot `.`, which again we need to escape, because like the `$` it has special meanings in regular expressions.

```
my $count = () = $menu =~ m/\$0\.00/g;
```

This whole line looks weird. We can break it up into a few lines to make it more readable.

```
my @matches = ( $menu =~ m/\$0\.00/g );
my $count = scalar @matches;
```

We need the `/g` switch on the regular expression match to make it match all occurrences. In list context, the match operation returns all matches (which will be the string `"$0.00"` a number of times). Because we want the count, we then force that into `scalar` context, which gives us the number of elements. That can be shortened to one line by the idiom shown above.